# the derivation of the conditional posterior for the Poisson model setting

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, posterior, change-point

When discussing the Poisson process with changing point (Carlin, Gelfand and Smith, 1992), the model is assumed as

[image]

I am not quite clear about the derivation of conditional posterior distribution based on the above model setting, especially the following part circled with red color

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the answer is in the part that you highlighted in blue. Once you consider the conditional posterior of $\lambda_1$ given the data, $k$ and $\lambda_2$, these parts are treated as fixed. So in your conditional posterior everything that does not involve $\lambda_1$ goes into the proportionality constant.

This leaves you with
$$P(\lambda_1|Y_1,...,Y_k,\lambda_2, k) \propto \left( \prod^{k}_{i=1}e^{-\lambda_1}\lambda_1^{Y_i}\right) \cdot \lambda_1^{a_0 - 1}e^{-b_0 \lambda_1}$$

Collecting terms gives:
$$P(\lambda_1|Y_1,...,Y_k,\lambda_2, k) \propto \lambda_1^{a_0 + \sum^k_{i=1}Y_i - 1}e^{-\lambda_1(b_0 + k)}$$
Since your likelihood is Poisson and the prior is Gamma distributed, this is a conjugate problem, i.e. the posterior is the same as the prior distribution, so the posterior is distributed as $$Ga(a_0 + \sum^{k}_{i=1}Y_i; b_0 + k)$$